# e(fx)clipse 0.9.0 on Kepler with Java 7

Tags: eclipse, javafx, eclipse-kepler, efxclipse

is it possible to **run** the **e(fx)clipse sample application** on **Kepler & Java7** at all ?

I took the steps, descripted in tutorial 4 to integrate the target definition(s)
https://wiki.eclipse.org/Efxclipse/Tutorials/Tutorial4

I tried the all-in-one-eclipse as well as upgrading a common kepler-eclipse with update-site http://download.eclipse.org/efxclipse/updates-released/0.9.0/site

However, the Sample Project JavaFX/Samples/e4 Media Application can not be compiled.

- With Target Definition "RCP 3x Platform", all! application dependencies can not be resolved
- With Target Definition "Target Platform Feature" a warning comes up, that the target version is newer than my current Eclipse installation. There are no comile errors anymore, but running the app I will get a lot of runtime errors like:
  Unresolved requirement: Require-Capability: osgi.ee; filter:="(&(osgi.ee=JavaSE)(version=1.8))"

Did anybody get the sample "e4 Media Application" working ?

My Eclipse: Kepler Service Release 2

My Java: JDK 7u40

============== EDIT ==============

Got it working, thanks to Tom!

1. Install fresh new Eclipse: http:// www.eclipse.org/downloads/packages/eclipse-rcp-and-rap-developers/keplersr2
2. Install Xtext 2.5.0, Update-Site: http:// download.eclipse.org/modeling/tmf/xtext/updates/composite/releases
3. Install e(fx)clipse, Update-Site: http:// download.eclipse.org/efxclipse/updates-released/0.9.0/site
4. Add new Target Platform, Update-Site: http:// download.eclipse.org/efxclipse/runtime-released/0.9.0/site
   Select FX Target -> Target Platform Feature

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The nightly runtime site already requires Java8 (see announcement on e(fx)clipse newsrpoup!)

If you want to run it on Java7 you need to use http://download.eclipse.org/efxclipse/runtime-released/0.9.0/Site for the target platform

Comment: Thanks! Got it working now with a fresh new install, see details above